# How we can share state object to another react file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

in the first react file i called an api to get some data and save it in this.state.Data

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Layout from "./Layout";

class Db extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      Data: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://breakingbadapi.com/api/characters`).then((res) => {
      const data = res.data;
      this.setState({ Data: data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>DB working</h1>;
  }
}

export default Db;
```

in the another react file i need to get this.props.Data from Db.js file but i dont know how to get it

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Db from "./Db";

class Filler extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
  }

  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}

export default Filler;
```

Comment: You should use redux or pass the data to child component as props.

Comment: Use redux or pass it as props

Answer (score 1):

for small projects you can use React ContextApi to save states in global level and use it inside components you want.

for big projects you can use state management libraries like Redux. it's too much for small projects.

Comment: "...Redux. it's too much for small projects." This is debatable, and rather opinionated. Redux is useful for any sized app of significant purpose where you want a single global app state and an "event bus".

Comment: @DrewReese Please read this https://redux.js.org/faq/general#when-should-i-use-redux . Quote from Dan Abramov in the page: "I would like to amend this: don't use Redux until you have problems with vanilla React."

Comment: Does Gaearon make all your decisions for you? I stand by my statement. What constitutes a small or big project is subjective and only one bullet point, of several, in the link you shared. I think Dan's point parallels my comment about "significant purpose", and you do realize those are just guidelines hopefully. Thanks for sharing though.

Comment: Does Gaearon make all your decisions for you? Absolutely not, but he knows loooooot more than me about redux.